Is there a way to insert keyframe to modify the animation with "Cell Fracture" quick effect?
Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EdOKufIs5HpDmX1rdtpBD_sBEGDDLtmZkCm8RdaRzLdZHw?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=aGvMzY
I can't seem to find away to insert a keyframe. I only want to change the starting time of it. For example: I want the explosion to start at 50 frames, but first 49 frames remain untouched.
The tutorial Im following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtoHQnQATck&ab_channel=BlenderVitals

it depends on what you wanna have. If you wanna have still a simulation, Johns answer is totally right. If you "just" wanna move your animation (because it is ready) you could e.g. bake your rigid body (object->rigid body-> bake to keyframes) and then you can move that keyframes as you want.

Have you tried changing the Simulation Start frame under Scene Properties > Rigid Body World > Cache?

Also make sure that the Simulation End frame matches the end frame on the Timeline.
